# Double filter with lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, filtering

I'm creating a product edit form in WPF. This form has text boxes for the following properties: `Id`, `Code`, `Width`, `Height`, and `Color`.

`Id` and `Code` cannot repeat, so I want make a "checking" for `Code` repeat in my `Code_TextChanged` event.

I have tried the following lambda expression for checking:

```
// List<Product> products = …;
if (products.Where(x => x.code.Equals(Code.Text))
            .Count(g => !g.id.Equals(Id.Text)) > 0)
    CodeExist = true;
```

I don't know why, when I opened a register, it will mark `CodeExist` as true.

How to I can make a condition, for filter `product.code.Equals(Code.Text)` and `!product.id(Id.Text)`?

Comment: Off-topic: **1.** Instead of `items.Count(…) > 0`, use `items.Any(…)`. It is likely to perform better, since the exact count won't have to be computed. **2.** Regarding the parameter names of your lambda functions, I was wondering why you chose `x` and `g`, and not just `p` (or `product`), which would seem easier to follow, given a collection named `products`. **3.** If you want a double filter (`.Where`), nothing would have stopped you from the obvious solution of simply chaining two `.Where`s in your query (even though it wouldn't have been an optimal solution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add multiple conditions using "&&" (which is equivalent to "AND" in SQL) or "||" (which is equivalent to "OR" in SQL).

You can also use the LINQ "Any()" method to return true if one or more elements in the collection match a condition.

So your if statement would read:

```
if(products.Any(x=>x.code.Equals(Code.Text) && !x.id.Equals(Id.Text))){
     CodeExists = true;
}
```

EDIT: Fixed minor typo with "!" placement.

Comment: Sorry, minor typo. The "!" goes before the "x."